# Reading a tab separated data from text file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a *.txt* file which has *tab* (`\t`) and *semicolon* (`;`) separated data, and I want to read the data and create JSON object. I tried the regular expression but I am not able to create a proper regular expression. Any help would be appreciated.

**test.txt**

```
sam tory 22;raj kumar 24
```

**output.json**

```
[
    {
        "Fname": "sam",
        "lastname": "troy",
        "Age": "22",
    },
    {
        "Fname": "raj",
        "lastname": "kumar",
        "Age": "24",
    }
]
```

Comment: Use `fs` to read the file, then `split` by `;` and parse your data.

Comment: but what about tab separated data ?

Comment: Split by `\t`, I just test and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the JavaScript [`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function to split your text.

```js
var r = [];
var t = "sam tory 22;raj kumar 24";
var v = t.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
  var w = v[i].split("\t");
  r.push({
    Fname: w[0],
    lastname: w[1],
    Age: w[2]
  });
}
console.log(r);
```

Comment: This answer does not consider character escaping.  It's unlikely that there will be an embedded tab in a field, but it's possible.  For other delimiters (e.g. comma) there may be a higher probability of characters that must be escaped (quotes, delimiter, carriage return).  In my opinion, Alfredo's answer is a more reliable solution, overall.

Answer (score 11):

Use the `fs` module to read the contents of the file.

```
var content = fs.readFileSync("profiles.tsv", "utf8");
```

Then map through the individual entries to transform them into an object:

```js
const file = 'sam     tory  22;raj  kumar   24';
const json = file.split(';')
    .map(profile => {
        const [Fname, lastname, Age] = profile.split('\t');
        return { Fname, lastname, Age };
    });

console.log(json)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the library csvtojson: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson

Here is testing code:

```
const csv=require('csvtojson')

const filePath='test.tsv'

var main = async () => {
  const jsonArray = await csv({delimiter:'\t'}).fromFile(filePath);
  console.log("jsonArray:", jsonArray);
}

main()
```